# MVC architecture example using JSF 2.0 and EJB 3?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsf, ejb

Somebody knows an example of this? an application made with JSF 2.0 and EJB 3? directory structure, etc, those kind of things, I’m trying to approach the best way to create a Java EE app using those technologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at the Glassfish Samples or the Java Petstore application that are developed in compliance to the blueprints:

Glassfish Samples: http://glassfish-samples.java.net/
Java Pet Store: https://blueprints.dev.java.net/petstore/
BluePrints: http://java.sun.com/blueprints/code/projectconventions.html

Comment: Java pet store is no longer available?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to check the [Java EE 6 samples](http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/code/) (the JSF 2.0, the Weld and EJB 3.1 samples) and the [Chapter 2. Using the Tutorial Examples](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/gfiud.html) of the [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/).